# Apparent Bug with Python Usign Selenium : issue with PosixPath

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, selenium, posix

Good evening,
I have started a django project, using python 3.7 and Django 3.1.5
When I launch my unitary tests, they run perfectly.
When running selenium, this is what I get:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/fabricejaouen/Documents/OC_Parcours_Python/advocacy_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/fabricejaouen/Documents/OC_Parcours_Python/advocacy_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 133, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/Users/fabricejaouen/Documents/OC_Parcours_Python/advocacy_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1305, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/Users/fabricejaouen/Documents/OC_Parcours_Python/advocacy_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1317, in serve
    return serve(request, final_rel_path, document_root=self.get_base_dir())
  File "/Users/fabricejaouen/Documents/OC_Parcours_Python/advocacy_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 36, in serve
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
  File "/Users/fabricejaouen/Documents/OC_Parcours_Python/advocacy_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/_os.py", line 17, in safe_join
    final_path = abspath(join(base, *paths))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py", line 80, in join
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

The strange part of it is:

- no Error linked to my project is raised,
- the Selenium tests pass perfectly and here is my Selenium setup:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
import os
class CustomUserTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    fixtures = ['users.json']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        cls.browser = Firefox()
        cls.browser.implicitly_wait(10)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.browser.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_plaid_10_authenticate_on_the_website(self):
        """
            The user wants to authenticate in order to have access to
            the functionalities of the website
        """
        self.browser.get(os.path.join(self.live_server_url, ''))
```

Therefore, I can go on with my project, however, this puzzling issue bothers me.
If anyone of you has a hint, I will be more than happy.
Kind regards.

Comment: Looks like your STATIC_ROOT is not defined, but you are using `django.contrib.staticfiles.views.static` in your urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

This was the point. Adding:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

to my settings solved the issue.
Thx.